# Why private (RFC1918) addresses are not resolved by my provider?

Tags: networking, dns

I use [gandi.net](http://gandi.net) to manage my domains. A fragment of the zone:

```
ext 10800 IN A 87.218.103.15
server 10800 IN A 192.168.0.1
mail 10800 IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
```

When testing these three entries at home (French provider [Free](http://portail.free.fr/)):

- `ext` and `mail` are resolved
- `server` is not resolved

When testing for instance from an AWS machine, all three are resolved.

The `SOA` is the same when queried from both places.

Short of having my internet box filtering DNS requests which resolve to a private (RFC 1918) address, I have no clue about the difference of behaviour. What could be the cause?

Comment: Shouldn't the "server 10800 IN A 192.168.0.1" be a public address instead of a private one?

Comment: No, this is a server which has a private address. The difference in behavior for that entry  with `mail` (which is a `CNAME` to a public address) and `ext` (which is an `A` record pointing to a public address) are the heart of my question.

Comment: See RFC1918, specifically, "Indirect references to [private] addresses should be contained within the enterprise. Prominent examples of such references are *DNS Resource Records* and other information referring to internal private addresses. In particular, *Internet service providers should take measures to prevent such leakage*."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some DNS resolvers discard such replies to avoid [DNS rebinding attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding); for example, your home gateway might be running dnsmasq with `--stop-dns-rebind` enabled.

Try querying a public Internet DNS server directly, e.g. 8.8.8.8 or 4.2.2.2:

```
dig @4.2.2.2 server.example.com
```

Comment: Right on spot, thank you. Following your idea, I found on the dev forums of my provider exactly this reason for the filtering (http://dev.freebox.fr/bugs/task/9909 - in French)